# Issue On Displaying Pages with Post Name Permalink

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, pages, urls, page-template

I have a simple Theme like below

[image]

Right now when I navigate to localhost and site root directory I am able to see content from `header.php` , `footer.php` and `page.php`.

then, I simply generated some pages for Navigation bar and to get a better URL I updated the permalink from `default` to `Post Name` format

[image]

Now while I have the the clean Ur as: `Permalink: http://localhost/RumiPress/eyeglasses/`

[image]

When I click to view the page I am getting
[image]

I Google this and find some hints about the `(.htaccess)` so I just copied same format as [Cedex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creatingandediting(.htaccess)) 
[image]

but still getting same result. Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work permalinks properly, you have to enable 'mod_rewrite' module in your apache server. Other wise it could not run .htaccess file and that is why it shows 'Not found'. It will be working if the permalink is disabled or set to default, right?

Comment: Hi Hakkim, thanks for reply but can you please let me know how I can enable it on WAMP? and how about Server side I mean I am using Awardspace.com free hosting , in this how can I do this?

Comment: I think, the Awardspace.com support team could help you on this. That will take only few minuets to do. Try to get their support.